# How to implement queue in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-structures

[image: web page]

image description:

clicking on an icon will do its action after icons task completed, it should get terminated. but some icons can stay active in combination with other icons.

Problem:

I have more than 30 options to work with. I want to track all the items. whenever an item is clicked, it should be inserted. and when clicked again it should be removed. if an item is already active, and if it is clicked again, then it should be removed. some options are like they can stay with other combinations of options.

What I did till now:

I implemented two methods for this, execute and terminate to do insertion and removal of last clicked item. If I'll go with the same process, then there will be a lot of if else, which I don't want to implement. I thought to implement a queue, which will help me in tracking all the options selected by the user.

How to implement a queue in **angular 5** or more? If there is any other better approach I can go through, suggest me.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any way you can put this on codepen to get a better understanding of what you're trying to do?

Comment: How would **you** implement a queue in JavaScript? It would really just be an array with `unshift()`, `pop()`, and some custom methods? In Angular you'd probably iterate over that array with `*ngFor`. What have you tried so far specifically?

Comment: Shift/unshift method is costly in terms of performance, if I am not wrong. So, I am trying to avoid array.

Comment: Yes you are wrong and you are only doing this occasionally when a user interaction event occurs

Comment: @charlietfl, it's not occasional sir. I am using for commands. a user can click on any commands present on the webpage. for example- menu commands in an explorer window. most of the things will be available on this webpage as well.

Comment: By *"occasional"* I mean you aren't running it in a long repetitive loop type situation. Splicing arrays is very very common in modern web apps and is what you want to use for what you are asking

Comment: @ngWolf seriously, we're shooting all over the place, please, show us what you mean: https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: https://angular-vlwniu.stackblitz.io

Please check this stackblitz link. Icons can be referred from image in question

Comment: @Stavm I cannot reproduce exactly as it is dependent on an external library due to licensing issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick implementation of a queue in TypeScript. You can modify it to use in Javascript.

```
class Node<T> {
  next: Node<T>;
  constructor(public data: T) {
  }
}

export class Queue<T> {
  head: Node<T>;
  tail: Node<T>;

  constructor() {
    this.head = this.tail = null;
  }

  enqueue(data: T): void {
    const node = new Node(data);

    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      this.head = this.tail = node;
      return;
    }

    this.tail.next = node;
    this.tail = node;
  }

  dequeue(): T {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    const data = this.head.data;

    if (this.tail === this.head) {
      this.head = this.tail = null;
    } else {
      this.head =  this.head.next;
    }

    return data;
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.head === null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Please try it

Create a Class

```
 export class Queue<T> {
  _store: T[] = [];
  public push(val: T) {
    this._store.push(val);
  }
  public pop(): T | undefined {
    return this._store.shift();
  }
}
```

You can pass any type to T Parameter of the class. It's a Class Constraint

and here is my demo class for passing as Parameter to Queue

```
export class Demo{

    public val1:number;
    public val2:string;

}
```

How to use it

```
    let Qu:Queue<Demo>  = new Queue<Demo>();
    Qu.push({val1:1, val2:"Asanga1"});
    Qu.push({val1:2, val2:"Asanga2"});

    console.log(Qu.pop());
```

Here is the out put in console

```
>Object {val1: 1, val2: "Asanga1"}
```

So it pull out the first one in the queue

Please try it .

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript ES6 provides implementations to Queue and Stack datastructures out of the box using the Array object.

Please refer to this post.

https://dev.to/dilantha111/stacks-and-queues-in-js-with-es6-classes-and-array-20kh

To get the benefit of Angular types, use the `Array<T>` interface.

Answer (score -1):

Queue in JavaScript:

```
// initialization
const queue = []
// insertion
queue.unshift(/* element here */)
// removing
const removedElement = queue.shift()
// first element
const firstElement = queue[0]
// last element
const lastElement = queue[queue.length - 1]
```